# How to validate length and restrict textfield to Numeric, alphanumeric, and alpha characters only in iOS

Tags: ios

I want to validate length and restrict Numeric, alphanumeric, and alpha characters only in iOS, can anyone help me out to achieve this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found best Way to tackle this thing. Works like a champ :)

inside .m file

```
//#define CHARACTERS @" ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz"

//#define CHARACTERS_NUMBERS  [CHARACTERS stringByAppendingString:@"1234567890"]
///// Inside shouldChangeCharactersInRange 

///////////>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>> 

if(textField== txtFldAlpha)
    {

        //Alpha only

        NSUInteger newLength = [textField.text length] + [string length] - range.length;

        NSCharacterSet *unacceptedInput =
        [[NSCharacterSet characterSetWithCharactersInString:CHARACTERS] invertedSet];

        // Create array of strings from incoming string using the unacceptable
        // characters as the trigger of where to split the string.
        // If array has more than one entry, there was at least one unacceptable character
        if ([[string componentsSeparatedByCharactersInSet:unacceptedInput] count] > 1)
            return NO;
        else 
            return YES&&(newLength < 26);
        return YES;
    }

///////////<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<

///////////>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>

if(textField==txtFldNumeric)
    {
        //Num only

        NSUInteger newLength = [textField.text length] + [string length] - range.length;
        NSCharacterSet *nonNumberSet = [[NSCharacterSet decimalDigitCharacterSet] invertedSet];

        if ([[string componentsSeparatedByCharactersInSet:nonNumberSet] count] > 1)
            return NO;
        else 
            return YES&&(newLength < 6);
        return YES;

    }

///////////<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<

///////////>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>

if(textField==txtFieldNumAlphaSpecial)
    {
        //Num,Alpha,Special field

        NSUInteger newLength = [textField.text length] + [string length] - range.length;
        return (newLength > 50) ? NO : YES;
    }    
///////////<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<
```

Answer (score 3):

You can form regular expression strings and use it. Please find a sample a code below for allowing only alphabets and space.

```
- (BOOL)textField:(UITextField *)textField shouldChangeCharactersInRange:(NSRange)range replacementString:(NSString *)string
{
    NSString *stringPlace = @"[a-z  A-Z]*";
    NSPredicate *testPlace = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"SELF MATCHES %@", stringPlace]; 
    BOOL matches = [testPlace evaluateWithObject:string];

    // if it does not match the regular expression and more than 5 characters 
    if (!matches && string.length > 5)
    {
        return NO;
    }
    return YES;
}
```